# How to add half a space beneath vertical bar?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have two lines of text with a horizontal bar between them. I want half a space beneath the bar. So far I can only get half a space above the bar. I can do this by adjust line spacing to 1.5

I create the vertical bar with following [these instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-or-remove-horizontal-lines-or-rules-9bf172f6-5908-4791-9bb9-2c952197b1a9).

[image: screen shot of example]
Note how the green arrow points to a space, I want that bellow the line.

Answer (score 0):

Select the row that the line is in, so that it is highlighted (typically by clicking off to the left just outside the margins).

Open Paragraph Options from the Home tab.

In the Spacing section, instead of changing line spacing, increase After to about 6 pt (or whatever size you prefer).

Example with 10 pt after each line:

[image]

EDIT: just a sec, a bit more testing shows it might be a bit more complicated. Adding a line above and below a paragraph can move each line to be closer to the text. But you can change it back using Paste Format referencing a line that is how you want it.